# Assigning Weight to MultiClass Variable

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model

I am working on an academic project where I go through the bug database and classify the bug (a Multiclass Classification). After this classification, I would like to assign a weight to assign a weight based on the occurrence.

As an example, let us assume that we have a class called "Cli-related" which produces around 40% of the bug: How to assign a weight for this?

Simple way is # of bugs in this class / total No. of bugs. is this the way to do or does ML has different ways of assigning it.

I see that there is a `class_weight` parameter but was not aware of this usage.

Can someone help here please?